# findContours() does not work although the image being binary opencv

Tags: python, opencv

So Im trying to get contours for an image but it seems to be the wrong data type and I get this error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0)
>   /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:197:
>   error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)
>   [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode !=
>   CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function
>   'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

I read It could be a Problem with the image not being binary however in my case I already converted the image via threshold:

```
 im = cv2.imread("picture.jpg")

 cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 (thresh, im_t) = cv2.threshold(im, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

 im_tb = cv2.convertScaleAbs(im_t)  #this does not seem to help either

 (contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(im_tb,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

thank you for your help

Comment: What is in "mydirectory"`? Is that an image or a directory. cv2.imread() only reads one image, not a directory.

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56

Comment: Why areyou using `convertScaleAbs`?

Comment: Can you try: `im_tb.shape` and `im_tb.dtype` before `cv2.findContours`

Comment: @fmw42 I tried to replace the directory with something generic for the post ist is taking an .jpg .

Comment: I tried dtype before but accidentally put () behind it. The type is uint8 and the shape: (50, 250, 3)

Comment: @eldesgraciado I read about it on some different post but it does not work either way with or without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
   cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

you should use

```
   im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Otherwise, the conversion result is just discarded and you still have a 3-channel RGB image.